# JavaScript Pig Latin Converter Optimizations

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

Total newb here...looking for some examples of optimizing this pigLatin converter.

```
function pigLatin(str) {

  var vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
   if (vowels.includes(str[0])) {
    str = str + "way";
    return str;
  }
 
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.includes(str[i])) {
      var flopStr = str.substring(0, [i]) + "ay";
      var newStr = str.substring([i]) + flopStr;
      return newStr;
    }
  }
  
  if (!vowels.includes(str) === true) {
    str = str + "ay";
    return str;
  }
}
```

I am pretty happy that I can at least write something that works. I do; however, need some guidance on other methods of accomplishing the same task.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! The way this question is currently written, it lacks details and clarity. What are you trying to achieve? If you're looking for optimization - what exactly are you trying to optimize for? There's plenty of examples of a similar algorithm being implemented on the internet, even on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+pig+latin) - have you researched those?

Comment: I am looking for some other ways of doing this. I used the looping too much I think , and I am betting there is likely a more efficient method.

Comment: Expected output is: - If a word begins with a consonant, take the first consonant or consonant cluster, move it to the end of the word, and add 'ay' to it.
If a word begins with a vowel, just add 'way' at the end.
Translate the provided string to Pig Latin. Input strings are guaranteed to be English words in all lowercase.

Comment: I think there's a 'let' missing in your for loop. And thanks for the logic, it would be best if you could include it at the beginning of your answer

Comment: Are you saying your code works? If you are looking for optimisations, then maybe it would be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)... but follow their guidelines.

Comment: Passing array literals as arguments to `substring` is certainly not what you are supposed to do: those get converted to numbers, which luckily results in the intended value.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without any looping, working with a regex and the index of the first vowel

```js
function pigLatin(str) {

  let lC = str.toLowerCase()
  
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  
  let regex = /[aeiou]/
  
  let fVI = lC.search(regex) // firstVowelIndex
  
  switch(fVI) {
    case 0: 
      return lC+'way';
    default:
      return lC.substring(fVI) + lC.substring(0,fVI) + 'ay'
  }
}

console.log(pigLatin('coding'))  // 'odingcay'

console.log(pigLatin('addict'))  // addictway
```

(an improvement you could adopt in your version is to convert the string to lower case and remove uppercase vowels from the array)